# How to explain such esoteric JS code

Tags: javascript, jsfuck

This code is equal to `alert(1)`, but how does it work ? I don't see `eval` here.

```
/ㅤ/-[ㅤ=''],ﾠ=!ㅤ+ㅤ,ㅤㅤ=!ﾠ+ㅤ,ㅤﾠ=ㅤ+{},ﾠㅤ=ﾠ[ㅤ++],ﾠﾠ=ﾠ[ﾠㅤㅤ=ㅤ
],ﾠㅤﾠ=++ﾠㅤㅤ+ㅤ,ㅤㅤㅤ=ㅤﾠ[ﾠㅤㅤ+ﾠㅤﾠ],ﾠ[ㅤㅤㅤ+=ㅤﾠ[ㅤ]+(ﾠ.ㅤㅤ+ㅤﾠ)[ㅤ]+ㅤㅤ[ﾠㅤﾠ]+ﾠㅤ+ﾠﾠ+ﾠ
[ﾠㅤㅤ]+ㅤㅤㅤ+ﾠㅤ+ㅤﾠ[ㅤ]+ﾠﾠ][ㅤㅤㅤ](ㅤㅤ[ㅤ]+ㅤㅤ[ﾠㅤㅤ]+ﾠ[ﾠㅤﾠ]+ﾠﾠ+ﾠㅤ+"(ㅤ)")()
```

Comment: This is known as `JSFuck` (that's the actual name), and there's a pretty good write-up on [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck).

Comment: @ObsidianAge That, plus a bunch of weird unicode variable names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [JSFuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck), an esoteric programming language, that is actually valid JavaScript, so you don't need any special interpreter/compiler to run it.

The most popular one involves the use of just 6 characters (`[]()!+`), but yours is a bit different since it also uses `/`, `=`, `"`, `'`, `,`, `{`, `}` and  (*blank*).

It works by taking advantage of some nice features of JavaScript.

For instance, we know that `[]` is a truthy value, therefore `![]` yields `false`.

With that same logic, we can get `true` by executing `!![]`.

Numbers can be achieved too. We know that `false` is equal to `0`, so the following expression makes sense: `0 + false == 0`, right ? And it does. We know that `false` can be written as `![]`, and we know that we can omit the `0` on the left-side of the expression: `+![] == 0`.

Same can be said with `true` and `1`: `+!![]`

The number `2` can be achieved by adding up two `1`s: `(+!![])+(+!![])`, and so on.

With logic like these you can do pretty much anything.

For instance, a popular way to get the letter `"a"` is by producing a `NaN` result, converting it to string (`"NaN"`), and then getting the letter at index `1`, which is `"a"`.

Ok so.. We know we can get `"alert(1)"`, but how do we execute this?

We can't use `eval`, because that will require to use characters not allowed on JSFuck.

Well, the way most people do it is like this:

- Identify a well-known function of `Array.prototype`, let's say `indexOf`
- Obtain its [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) instance
- Pass in stringified code to this constructor
- Execute the result

So, as a summary:

```
// You can try this on your browser!
[]["indexOf"]["constructor"]("alert(1)")()
```

We know that we can generate alphabetic characters on JSFuck, and we also know we can generate numbers, so that line of code up there is actually very possible.